# Drawbacks of Tomcat Http11NioProtocol

Tags: tomcat, nio

With Tomcat 6.0.x, we can use [Http11NioProtocol](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Nio_Implementation) and get scalable performance. Is there any specific reason/drawback of using Http11NioProtocol, that Tomcat is not using this protocol as a default protocol?

Answer (score 31):

In the general context of NIO, it usually pays to **run some production benchmark measurements** to ensure you are getting the performance you think you are.  Remember that `Http11NioProtocol` does some odd things, like simulated blocking, to achieve drop-in connector behavior--this is not free and could potentially be less performant that the default `Http11Protocol` connector.

We are satisfied with the performance of our webapp  with the default `Http11Protocol` connector.  Hundreds of millions of HTTP requests per month on 5 year old hardware.

If performance really is a concern, you should investigate taking the more labor intensive step of using the [AJP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html) `Http11AprProtocol`.  It is a part native connector written in C which reportedly is solidly faster.  But getting it up and running takes more than a `server.xml` change.

I've personally had problems with `Http11NioProtocol` and a 3rd party open source API library.  (OpenAMF, a dated AMF0 POJO thingy.)  Meaning, it didn't work.  But if it works for you, then cool.

In summary:

- The benefits of the NIO connector are debatable
- Run benchmarks
- Consider the AJP connector

Comment: tc made NIO as default connector in version 8. (Http11Protocol means different now.)